# Google Chat API get list of messages for a space

Tags: python, attributeerror, google-chat

I am trying to get [this example](https://developers.google.com/workspace/chat/list-messages) in Python working.

```
def get_msg():
    creds = None
    if os.path.exists('token.json'):
        creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/chat.spaces', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/chat.messages')

    chat = build('chat', 'v1', credentials=creds)
    result = chat.spaces().messages().list(name='spaces/123456789').execute()
    print(result)


def main():
    get_msg()
```

This error comes up:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\30_py\google\chat\test_chat.py", line 64, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\30_py\google\chat\test_chat.py", line 57, in main
    get_msg()
  File "C:\30_py\google\chat\test_chat.py", line 46, in get_msg
    result = chat.spaces().messages().list(name='spaces/123456789').execute()
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'Resource' object has no attribute 'list'
```

I tested the authorization and the space name in the [API explorer](https://developers.google.com/workspace/chat/api/reference/rest/v1/spaces.messages/list) and it worked. I was able to get a list of spaces using a different endpoint so the credentials/token/logic works. However, I am stuck trying to get the endpoint working i.e. being able to fix this attribute error. Any ideas and recommendations are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `name` argument in `list()`. You need to give space id to `parent` as `"spaces/{space}"`.
Use [API Reference](https://developers.google.com/workspace/chat/api/reference/rest/v1/spaces.messages/list) whenever in doubt.